# 'Worse' vs 'less good'

Tags: adjectives, comparative-degree

Page 263 of Garner's fourth reads

> *Depend* typically takes *on* (or, **less good**, *upon*). When a clausal complement follows the verb, to omit the *on* is a casualism—

What differences does using *[worse](https://oed.com/oed2/00287305)* instead of *less good* highlight?

Comment: _Worse_ is the comparative of _bad_. **Depend upon** is perfectly good English, but the author considers it not as good as **depend on**.

Comment: ***Less good*** is still ***good*** - just not so good as something else. But ***worse*** is always ***bad*** (and usually, it was already "bad" before it got "worse").

Comment: @always **bad**? https://oed.com/oed2/00287305

Comment: I don't understand the point of your link. Is there something *specific* there that's making you think ***worse*** might not always imply ***bad***?

Comment: @FumbleFingers [https://books.google.es/books?id=T7v9DQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT316&dq=%20Maradona%20was%20worse%20than%20Pele&hl=es&pg=PT316#v=onepage&q=Maradona%20was%20worse%20than%20Pele&f=false](_In Italy everyone was arguing about whether I [Maradona] was better or worse than Pelé_). Logically, neither Maradona nor Pele were bad players.

Comment: That's a "pathological" (non-typical) example context, where only the specific *better OR worse* allows it to be compatible with the "fact" that neither Maradona nor Pele were bad players. If (after arguing about it) everyone in Italy agreed that Maradona was worse than Pelé, that would only be "valid" if we accept that *both* players were bad.